# SVG Transformation

Tags: svg, rotatetransform

I want to move every shape present on S.V.G 600px down, as my previous S.V.G's initial coordinates was at "bottom-left" but in my new S.V.G, it's at the "top-left" of S.V.G, so to display the shapes of previous S.V.G on new S.V.G I just used to add the Previous S.V.G height i.e. 600px into Y-translation and it's working fine with shape like:

```
<g id="shape3165-80" transform="translate(105.375,-208.875)"></g>
```

As the new points are (105.375, 391.125) which is correct as from bottom it's 208.875 above.

But in the case of rotated shapes, it's not showing on correct position as on rotation it's translation point had been changed, for example:
In case of:

```
<g id="shape3164-77" transform="translate(263.251,868.355) rotate(180)"></g>
```

so on adding 600px it's coordinates becomes (263.251, 1468.355) which display them out of S.V.G box. 
So I want to find:

1. The initial translate point of the shape before the rotation of 180deg.
2. Then add 600px to it.
3. Then again rotate it with 180deg.

So my question is am I doing it in right manner? Would you help me to find out the solution or formula for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Because the shape is rotated 180 degrees, you will need to subtract 600 from the Y coordinate instead of adding 600.

So the second example should be:

```
<g id="shape3164-77" transform="translate(263.251,268.355) rotate(180)"></g>
```

Alternatively, add your 600 before the other transforms:

```
<g id="shape3164-77" transform="translate(263.251,868.355) rotate(180) translate(0,600)"></g>
```

(Because of the way the `transform` attribute works, you can think of transforms being applied from right to left.  So to have one applied first, it has to be put at the end).

Comment: Thank you, but I want a general formula because 180deg is variable and can be anything. so what i have to add if the shape is rotated at 45deg or 46deg or 47deg??